# How to improve emacs font rendering

Tags: fonts

[image: Comparison of emacs -nw vs emacs with GUI]

On the left: emacs in console mode. On the right: emacs with GUI.

Running 24.5.1 on Arch linux. Both my console and emacs have the font set to Inconsolata 12. What can I do to make the emacs with GUI fonts look "smoother"?

[ETA more detail:]

I tried making a `/etc/fonts/local.conf` file which [specified anti-aliasing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_configuration#Anti-aliasing). It made no difference. (I'm not using Infinality.)

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22711440/54056) I should find out the GNOME settings and make a `.Xresources` file that emacs would use. But I didn't have any luck there.

From gnome-tweak-tool I had:

- Hinting: medium
- Antialiasing: Grayscale
- Scaling Factor: 1.0

I couldn't figure out what "Antialiasing Grayscale" is equivalent to in Xresources-speak...

```
$ xrdb -query | grep Xft
Xft.dpi:    96
Xft.antialias:  1
Xft.hinting:    1
Xft.hintstyle:  hintmedium
Xft.rgba:   none
```

This is what was there before I made a `.Xresources` file and it seems basically correct? I tried changing `Xft.rgba` to `rgb` but I couldn't appreciate any difference.

Comment: Looks like your GUI Emacs uses different anti-aliasing settings.  It's long since I've used Arch, but I do remember that you had to set some Xresources for Emacs‘ anti-aliasing settings.

Comment: Tweak **FontConfig's** settings https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Infinality#Usage if you are Infinality user or https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_configuration#Fontconfig_configuration

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217920/loading-x-resources-from-xresources-and-xdefaults-for-emacs

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure about how to **apply** these settings, but your desired settings seem to be at odds with your picture. The one on the left (your preferred one?) has **RGB antialiasing** and **none-low hinting**, whereas on the right you have **grayscale** antialiasing and much **higher** hinting (zoom the picture until you see the individual pixels to see what I mean).

So your GUI emacs is obeying your .Xresources, and the terminal emulator is doing its own thing.

To recreate the settings for the picture on the left, you should go with:

- RGB antialiasing
- low or no hinting

Answer (score 0):

Try using `font-manager` (Linux). font-manager will let you update Emacs font rendering on the fly (at least emacs-wayland which is using GTK I believe). It seems like Gnome and GTK applications default to using grayscale antialiasing which looks blurry to me.

https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/font-manager/
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/font-manager/